# laravel 5.4 can i use custom method inside a where clause

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to call a method inside a custom model function during query building but getting error.This way is it possible.Actually i'm trying to break the query in two function because filterData may be long.

In model, i wrote like this

```
public function get_filter_sql2($query, $filterData){

        if( count($filterData) > 0 ){   

            foreach($filterData as $key=>$value){   

                if( $value!=''){

                    if( $key == 'title' ){
                        $query->where('b.title', 'LIKE', '%'.$value.'%');
                    }
                    if( $key == 'bannercatID' ){
                        $query->where('b.bannercatID', '=', $value);
                    }
                    if( $key == 'status' ){
                        $query->where('b.status', '=', $value);
                    }

                }
            }
        }   
        return $query; 
    }



function scopeGet_all_records2($query,$filterData, $per_page){ 
        //DB::enableQueryLog();
        $result = DB::table('banner as b')
                ->leftJoin('banner_category as bc', 'bc.bannercatID', '=', 'b.bannercatID')    
                ->select('*')           
                ->where( function ($query) use ($filterData){               
                    $this->get_filter_sql2($query, $filterData);
                 })         
                ->orderBy('b.bannercatID', 'ASC')
                ->paginate($per_page)
                ;
        //$result = DB::getQueryLog(); 
        //print_r($result);
        if( count($result) > 0 ){
            $result = $result;
        }
        else{
            $result = false;
        }       
        return $result;             

    }
```

Comment: any errors you want to share?

Comment: You got an error because something is wrong. More info in your error description.

Comment: Actually in controller echo $records->isEmpty(); not working  and count returning 1 when there is a empty record.that's why giving errror

Answer (score 0):

You should use more relations instead of raw DB queries. But thats up to you. In the end code would be more elegant with Eloquent.

I think your issue is that you are using `$this` instead of `$query` in the where anonymous function.

```
->where( function ($query) use ($filterData){               
    $query->get_filter_sql2($query, $filterData);
})
```

Comment: Actually in controller echo $records->isEmpty(); not working and count returning 1 when there is a empty record.that's why giving error otherwise my code is working properly

Comment: Try changing `if( count($result) > 0 )` to `if( $result->count() )` this is a proper Laravel method.